# Is there any way to proper order events in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, events

I am having a lot of headaches trying to make $watch executes before event on an element of a form (a checkbox to be more precise). The only browser that works is FF.

```
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function($v){

                    console.log("1 = "+$v);

                });

                // elem corresponds to the element in form (i.e.: checkbox)
                elem.bind('change', function(evt){

                    console.log("2 = "+control.$modelValue);

                    scope.$digest();
                });
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this work in all browsers?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is likely no guaranteed ordering of events in any browser. My not just <checkbox ng-model="myVar" ng-change="myCallback()" /> /?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event are raised before the DOM was rendered (to allow manipulation) so if you want to use the values in the field after they were rendered you can use `$timeout`.

For example , check if a form field is dirty in a directive ...

```
elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {              
     if (event.which === 13) 
          scope.update();

     scope.check_dirty();
});

scope.check_dirty = function() {
    // wait for the DOM to finish rendering
    $timeout(function() {
        if ( elm.val().trim() !== scope.last_saved_value )
            elm.addClass('calc-dirty-input');
        else
            elm.removeClass('calc-dirty-input');
    },0);
};  
...
```